# Windows 7 Ent DirectAccess client cannot browse over SMB

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012, direct-access

Environment is IP-HTTPS DirectAccess with a 2012 DA server and a mix of Windows 7 Enterprise and Windows 10 Pro clients.

I have one Windows 7 Enterprise client that shows up as connected to DA and can ping/RDP/https to intranet resources, but cannot browse over SMB to any server. Everything works fine with other Win7 and Win10 clients.

Not seeing any errors relating to DirectAccess locally or on the DirectAccess server. There are no firewall rules blocking outgoing SMB on the client. I've run the DirectAccess Client Troubleshooter tool and the only thing it finds is that it's unable to connect to the Group Policy server, as I'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this post while researching this problem myself... Here is a link to the solution that worked for me too: https://engineeringit.wordpress.com/2014/07/28/directaccess-unable-to-access-fileshares/

Was a bit scary doing this remotely... Basically scheduled a delayed restart, then deleted the IPHTTPSInterface from device manager & crossed my fingers. After about 10minutes, the device had reconnected to DirectAccess; I logged into it again & confirmed file shares (and thus group policy) were now working again.